# Get zeromq message data into std::vector<char>

Tags: c++, blob, zeromq

Given a zeromq message received like so:

```
zmq_msg_t messageIn;
int rc = zmq_msg_init(&messageIn);
rc = zmq_msg_recv(&messageIn, socket, 0);
```

I'd like to access the incoming message data and store it into a;

```
std::vector<char> inMsg;
```

Trying this;

```
std::memcpy(&inMsg, zmq_msg_data(&messageIn), zmq_msg_size(&messageIn));
```

Did not work.  Can anyone please offer suggestions on how to achieve this?

Comment: `memcpy` using inMsg address obviously did not do what you wanted because it does not point to a storage. ravi answered your question. using the  msg_str that he got you can iterate over characters using `msg_str.begin()` and `end()`. If you dont want to use `std::string` you could just use array.  `char *inMsg = new char[zmq_msg_size(&messageIn);` then `memcpy` into this array as you did.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason it isn't working is because you don't seem to be resizing your `vector` to the capacity of the data you are trying to copy into it. It also isn't working because you are passing in the address of the `vector` object to `memcpy` instead of the address of the data the `vector` is storing. The `vector` object typically just contains two pointers to the beginning and end of the storage it manages. What you want to access is a pointer to that storage which you can either get with `&inMsg[0]` or in C++11 `inMsg.data()`.

So try:

```
std::vector<char> inMsg(zmq_msg_size(&messageIn));
std::memcpy(inMsg.data(), zmq_msg_data(&messageIn), zmq_msg_size(&messageIn));
```

Comment: `memcpy` is generally bad. Consider `char* ptr = static_cast<char*>(zmq_msg_data(&messageIn)); inMsg.assign(ptr, ptr + zmq_msg_size(&messageIn));`

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like below.

```
zmq::message_t request;

socket.recv (&request);

std::string msg_str(static_cast<char*>(request.data()), request.size());
```

and then store strings in vector. It would be much easier for processing...

```
std::vector<std::string> strVec;
strVec.push_back(msg_str);
```

Comment: Yes receiving a message can be accomplished with std::string but it's not what I was asking.